# OrientDB fails to persist a Vertex, returns ORID but with null vertex eg v(null)[#3:4]

Tags: orientdb

I cant get OrientDB to persist an OrientVertex or an oDocument using the java API.
although its works when I use SQL and the OCommand.

trying  to persist a vertex with foll code

```
  val factory: OrientGraphFactory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:localhost/database", "admin", "admin");
  val graph = factory.getTx
  val oDocument: ODocument = UserEntityMapper.toODocument(user)
  println("ODocument =  = "+ oDocument)
  val orientVertex = new OrientVertex(graph, oDocument)
  println("BEFORE orientVertex  = "+ orientVertex)
  graph.commit()
  println("AFTER orientVertex  = "+ orientVertex)
```

I get debug printouts as

ODocument =  {phoneNumber:45435345,email:moses@email.com,dateOfBirth:-766198800000,lastName:Johnson,firstName:Moses,avatarURL:null,loginInfo:{providerID:credentials,providerKey:moses@email.com},userID:a8d96be9-1d09-4e8f-bf8d-6a0d32e1e5aa}

BEFORE orientVertex  = v(null)[#3:-2]

AFTER orientVertex  = v(null)[#3:4]

As you can see, the vertex is null. Nothing is persisted. I get an ORID that changes the cluster position number.

When I repeat the save the cluster position number is incremented

BEFORE orientVertex  = v(null)[#3:-3]

AFTER orientVertex  = v(null)[#3:7]

Why does this happen and how can I fix this please? There are no exceptions so i cant tell whats wrong. The cluster/table for User exists on the DB with all teh right fields.

I am using orientdb-community-2.2.0 and Scala.

regards

Comment: Actually the `null` in the `v(null)[#3:4]` is the vertex class name, this doesn't mean the vertex is `null`. Try to fetch the vertex by its id, something like `graph.getVertex("#3:4")`, what do you get?

Comment: thanks for the response .. I tried what you suggested and  "v(null)[#3:4]" was returned.

Comment: great that you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out at last. I was instantiating the ODocument without the class name. In

```
UserEntityMapper.toODocument(user)
```

I was doing the equivalent of this

```
new ODocument(Map("name"->"john", "city" -> "London"))
```

instead of this

```
new ODocument("User").fromMap(Map("name"->"john", "city" -> "London"))
```

So the DB did not pick up the User class.

Thanks [actual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36174/actual) for pointing me in the right direction